# Strange android emulator behavior - mixed landscape and horizontal views

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

This suppose to be a portrait view.... but it is kind of a mixed view. I tried many skins and nothing helps. I also tried using landscape skins but they apper the same.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that's a bug in the emulator; I've had it happen on my Hero with stock, Froyo, and Gingerbread ROMs.

Comment: How can it not be a bug? I want my app to be in portrait mode and its a bit tricky to work like that.

p.s. How do I know what is my ROM version

Comment: My point is it's probably a ROM / system library bug, not an emulator bug, since it happens on real phones too.  As for ROM version, it should be under Settings > About Phone.

Comment: I am new to android dev, I am trying to develope a droid version for my ios app. I understand what you say but I need an advice on what to do... How to continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve it yet but I just tried a sample project from the android SDK samples library and it worked perfectlly.

In a few days I'll know more about android dev and I hope I'll understand what happened here...

Answer (score 0):

(promoting this to answer)

I've seen this happen on my phone under multiple ROMs (Eclair + Sense, Froyo + CyanogenMod, Gingerbread + AOSP (with and without Cmod)), so it's probably not a bug in the emulator; more likely it's a bug in the base system libraries.  I've also occasionally seen it draw the status bar in the wrong orientation but everything else correctly.  Unfortunately, I don't know what to do about it; usually it corrects itself after several orientation changes, but once I had to reboot.  It seems to be more likely to happen in low memory situations, though.